# Prevent update of specific Firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

There is an extension I don't want to update, either automatically or manually. I don't even want to see that there are updates.

The [only advice](https://superuser.com/questions/210418/preventing-firefox-from-updating-specific-extensions) for this is many years old and doesn't work for the latest Firefox.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Addons page. (about:addons)
2. Click the add-on.
3. Next to *Automatic Updates*, click *Off*.

[image: Screenshot of an add-on page with Automatic Updates section visible]

Comment: This is for automatic updates. Like I said I also don't want manual updates, and I don't want to see it in the list of updates available. There was a way to do this, as the link shows, but it no longer works in FF59+.

Comment: @lonix Why do you want to prevent manual update? It's hard to do that by accident. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Like mentioned in the linked question, sometimes I update a bunch at a time, and forget not to update a particular one. Then I need to rollback to the old version. It's a pain, so I want to block updates for that extension. This was possible using an official Mozilla technique, just not anymore.